# How to show the years between two bootstrap date-pickers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I'm struggling here to find the number of year's between from date and to date in date-pickers actually I'm trying to print the numbers of years between selected by from date and to date. I have tried in one way but I'm not getting correct values, anybody can you please help me on it how to achieve it.

For example: this is the dates like 02-05-2023 - 01-04-2027 (4 years) I want showcase the number of years contract between the sleeted dates 02-05-2023 - 01-04-2027 Answer (4 years)

Request: if possible please show me example in js fiddle

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!-- font-awesome -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- datepicker styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">


    <form>

      <!-- Date Picker -->
      <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <div class="datepicker date input-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Choose Date" class="form-control" id="fecha1">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Date Picker -->

      <!-- Date Picker -->
      <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <div class="datepicker date input-group">
          <input onchange="myTest()" type="text" placeholder="Choose Date" class="form-control" id="fecha2">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Date Picker -->

      <p id="test"></p>
    </form>
  </div>


  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Datepicker -->
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        language: "es",
        autoclose: true,
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    function myTest() {
      var fdate = document.getElementById("fecha1").value;
      var tdate = document.getElementById("fecha2").value;

      var date1 = new Date(fdate);
      var date2 = new Date(tdate);

      var date1_ms = date1.getFullYear();
      var date2_ms = date2.getFullYear();

      var years = parseInt(tdate) - parseInt(fdate);
      var adminLim = document.querySelector('#test')
      adminLim.append(years)
    }
  </script>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using :

```
var date1_ms = date1.getFullYear();
var date2_ms = date2.getFullYear();
var years = date2_ms - date1_ms;
```

Since [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) is returning an `integer` representing the year for the given date according to local time. Returns NaN if the date is invalid.

Also use `.html()` instead of `.append()`, since `.html()` will replace everything but `.append()` will just append at the end.

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!-- font-awesome -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- datepicker styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">


    <form>

      <!-- Date Picker -->
      <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <div class="datepicker date input-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Choose Date" class="form-control" id="fecha1">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Date Picker -->

      <!-- Date Picker -->
      <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <div class="datepicker date input-group">
          <input onchange="myTest()" type="text" placeholder="Choose Date" class="form-control" id="fecha2">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Date Picker -->

      <p id="test"></p>
    </form>
  </div>


  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Datepicker -->
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        language: "es",
        autoclose: true,
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    function myTest() {
      var years = 0;
      var fdate = document.getElementById("fecha1").value;
      var tdate = document.getElementById("fecha2").value;

      var date1 = new Date(fdate);
      var date2 = new Date(tdate);

      var date1_ms = date1.getFullYear();
      var date2_ms = date2.getFullYear();
      
      years = date2_ms - date1_ms || 0;

      $('#test').html(years);
    }
  </script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: SelVazi I'm getting value zero(0) whatever I have selected.

Comment: I’m getting correct data ! How are you testing can you share more details

Comment: SelVazi Yes it's working when I selected data exactly. and thanks a lot dear

Comment: If you see it useful, can you accept my answer

Answer (score -1):

I afraid you passed the wrong argument to parInt(). My suggestion is that you should change `var years = parseInt(tdate) - parseInt(fdate);` to `var years = Math.abs(parseInt(date1_ms) - parseInt(date2_ms));`, and you would get the correct year gap.

Comment: Hai @tech-kz I have made changes on as you suggested but getting NaN instead of years.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the DOM update. ```
      adminLim.append(years)``` didn't update the ```<p id="test"></p>``` correctly. By only modifying the ```var years = parseInt(tdate) - parseInt(fdate);```, you would get several years concatenated together. As to getting NaN for my solution, I have't figured out why. I have tried several running editors, and I got the same answers like "222" or "5555" etc.  I think the solution from SelVazi works correctly. I guess the reason why you got 0 is that you didn't pick the correct date when you clicked the second calendar picker.